# In python How can I extract data from webservices response using suds

Tags: python, suds

I am using python 2.71. I got this response from webservices call using python and suds library. I would like to extract the value of tag problemName. How can I do that ?

(200, (TESTResult){
   ProblemList = 
      (ArrayList){
         Items = 
            (ArrayOfAnyType){
               Item[] = 
                  (Problem){

```
                 comment = None
                 name = None
                 problemName = "Sad"
                 relation = "Mother"
                 source = "Provider"
              },
              (Problem){

                 comment = None
                 name = None
                 problemName = "Stress"
                 relation = "Father"
                 source = "Provider"
              }

        }
  }
```

})

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove (200, (TESTResult) by calling webservice without faults=False parameter for example :

```
#client = Client(url, transport=t, faults=False)
client = Client(url, transport=t)

resp = client.service.getProblemHistory(ProblemRequest)
probs = resp.ProblemList.Items.Item
for prob in probs
    print "problem : " , prob.problemName
```